# Can't get preg_replace to work

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace

I'm hoping that i've just made a simple mistake which you can help rectify. Unfortunately I'm not very experienced with PHP.

I'm attempting to run two regular expressions over a string.

You'll notice the first one is attempting to locate the script and iframe, and then wrap a div around this.

The second one, is just attempting to replace "//" URLs with HTTP protocol - I realise this one can be done as a str_replace, which I have commented out below. I tested that the str_replace was working to ensure there wasn't any funny business with this function not being called and it worked fine. For some reason the preg_replace is basically being ignored and the string is unchanged.

Am I missing something obvious here?

I've tried a couple of online preg_replace tools and they appear to be correct.

```
function cleanseSpringboardEmbed($content)
{
    // run regex over the content to clean up the embed code from springboard and make compatible with IA.
    $patternWrapper = '/<script src="\/\/www.springboardplatform\.com\/js\/overlay"><\/script><iframe(.*)<\/iframe>/';

    $patternProtocol = '/<iframe src="\/\/cms.springboardplatform.com/';

    $holder = $content;

    $replacementWrapper = '<figure class="op-interactive">' . '$0' . '</figure>';
    $replacementProtocol = '<iframe src="http://cms.springboardplatform.com';

    //$holder = str_replace("//cms.springboardplatform.com","http://cms.springboardplatform.com", $holder);
    //$holder = str_replace("//www.springboardplatform.com","http://www.springboardplatform.com", $holder);

    preg_replace($patternWrapper, $replacementWrapper, $holder);
    preg_replace($patternProtocol, $replacementProtocol, $holder);
    return $holder;
}
```

Here's a sample of some input

```
<p>test<br />
<script src="//www.springboardplatform.com/js/overlay"></script><iframe id="crzy003_1621795" src="//cms.springboardplatform.com/embed_iframe/5365/video/1621795/crzy003/craziestsportsfights.com/10" width="600" height="400" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe><br />
test</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to assign modified holder value after performing [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). According to above manual page

> `preg_replace()` returns an array if the subject parameter is an array,
>   or a string otherwise.
>
> If matches are found, the new subject will be returned, otherwise
>   subject will be returned unchanged or `NULL` if an error occurred.

So you should modify your code to this:

```
<?php

function cleanseSpringboardEmbed($content)
{
    // run regex over the content to clean up the embed code from springboard and make compatible with IA.
    $patternWrapper = '/<script src="\/\/www.springboardplatform\.com\/js\/overlay"><\/script><iframe(.*)<\/iframe>/';

    $patternProtocol = '/<iframe src="\/\/cms.springboardplatform.com/';

    $holder = $content;

    $replacementWrapper = '<figure class="op-interactive">' . '$0' . '</figure>';
    $replacementProtocol = '<iframe src="http://cms.springboardplatform.com';

    //$holder = str_replace("//cms.springboardplatform.com","http://cms.springboardplatform.com", $holder);
    //$holder = str_replace("//www.springboardplatform.com","http://www.springboardplatform.com", $holder);

    $holder = preg_replace($patternWrapper, $replacementWrapper, $holder);
    $holder = preg_replace($patternProtocol, $replacementProtocol, $holder);
    return $holder;
}
```